# Rapidminer, sort and filter attributes

Tags: rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner, and I would like to order my attributes' per example, and then filter the 15th's highest values. Can someone give me a clue on that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you have an example set and for each row you want to sort the attributes and keep only the 15 biggest?

So imagine you have this random data set:

[image: current data]

You try to get this result for your first example (limited to 5 biggest attributes for simplicity):

[image]

This can be done by looping over your example set with `Loop Examples`, filter each row with `Filter Example Range`, then `Transpose` the rows to columns, which then again can be sorted with `Sort` and limited to the max 15 values using `Filter Example Range` again.

Please notice that these new examples (rows) cannot be easily represented in a single example set, since they assumingly all have different attributes in a different order, thus you will get a collection of separate, sorted example sets.

Here is an example process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.5.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <parameter key="number_examples" value="10"/>
        <parameter key="number_of_attributes" value="10"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" width="90" x="179" y="34">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="label"/>
        <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">remove label for clarity</description>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_examples" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="103" name="Loop Examples" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Filter Example Range" width="90" x="45" y="34">
            <parameter key="first_example" value="%{example}"/>
            <parameter key="last_example" value="%{example}"/>
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">only work on current example</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="transpose" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Transpose" width="90" x="179" y="34">
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">transpose the row to columns with attribute name and attribute value</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="rename" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename" width="90" x="313" y="34">
            <parameter key="old_name" value="id"/>
            <parameter key="new_name" value="Example%{example}AttributeName"/>
            <list key="rename_additional_attributes">
              <parameter key="att_1" value="Value"/>
            </list>
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">rename for clarity, include original &amp;quot;row&amp;quot; number in attribute name</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="sort" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Sort" width="90" x="447" y="34">
            <parameter key="attribute_name" value="Value"/>
            <parameter key="sorting_direction" value="decreasing"/>
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">sort decreasing by attribute value</description>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="filter_example_range" compatibility="7.5.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Filter Example Range (2)" width="90" x="581" y="34">
            <parameter key="first_example" value="1"/>
            <parameter key="last_example" value="5"/>
            <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">keep 5 attributes with biggest values</description>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Filter Example Range" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Example Range" from_port="example set output" to_op="Transpose" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Transpose" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Rename" from_port="example set output" to_op="Sort" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Sort" from_port="example set output" to_op="Filter Example Range (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Example Range (2)" from_port="example set output" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
        <description align="center" color="transparent" colored="false" width="126">Loop over all examples, current index is stored in the macro &amp;quot;example&amp;quot;</description>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Loop Examples" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Examples" from_port="output 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```